# From Date and To Date From Previous Weeks

Tags: c#-4.0

I am working in C#.Net. I need the From Date and To Date. 
For Ex : If i selected "Last Week" means, i should get 15th April - 21st April. 
" 2 Weeks Ago " means, 8th April - 14th April. Same as for 3 Weeks ago, 4 Weeks ago etc..

How to get the From Date and To Date..

Comment: yes..i had multiplied the week by 7. After that i should do some logic...i need some ideas in that...

Comment: That gives me no idea of what you tried. Why not _edit_ your question and add the code you have tried? Please explain exactly where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made a console program..itz working fine.. chek it out

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter week number");
            int week = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            var weekStartDay = DayOfWeek.Monday;
            int daysInAWeek = 7;
            DateTime thisWeekStarttingDate = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan((int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek - (int)weekStartDay, 0, 0, 0)).Date;

            DateTime fromDate = thisWeekStarttingDate.Subtract(new TimeSpan(daysInAWeek * week, 0, 0, 0));
            DateTime toDate = fromDate.AddDays(daysInAWeek-1);

            Console.WriteLine("from date:" + fromDate.ToShortDateString());
            Console.WriteLine("to date:" + toDate.ToShortDateString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var currentWeek_StartDate = GetStartWeekDate_By_Date(DateTime.Now.Date);

  var lastWeek_StartDate = GetStartWeekDate_By_WeekIndex(currentWeek_StartDate, -1);
  var lastWeek_EndDate = GetEndWeekDate_By_StartWeekDate(lastWeek_StartDate);


public static DateTime GetStartWeekDate_By_Date(DateTime date)
{
  return date.AddDays(-(int)date.DayOfWeek);
}
public static DateTime GetEndWeekDate_By_StartWeekDate(DateTime date)
{
  return date.AddDays(6);
}
public static DateTime GetStartWeekDate_By_WeekIndex(DateTime date, int weekIndex)
{
  return date.AddDays(weekIndex * 7);
}
```